# What is the practical limit to how many object classes you can detect with Faster RCNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision

I am trying to follow [this](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) tutorial where the Faster-RCNN-Inception-V2-COCO model from TensorFlow's model zoo is used to detect playing cards. I was wondering what is the practical limit to the number of object classes that I could use this to detect, specifically what I would want to do is to detect every letter in the English language(distinguish capital and lowercase from each other), number and mathematical symbol. Would this model work with that many different classes?

Also If I want to detect some words, would it make sense to label all characters that make up a word and also label the word(assuming there are only a few important words I want to actually detect).

Comment: Why not try it out and see?

Comment: The standard ImageNet competition uses 1000 classes, which can be handled without any problems.